# Syntax error on CREATE TRIGGER in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, mariadb, backend

I'm trying to create a trigger that will update a column in a podcast table to an average worked out from a sproc called during the trigger. I've been working on this trigger but seem to keep hitting this same error where my syntax is wrong, i thought I'd found a solution through changing the delimiter, however this issue happens even after this.

The trigger I'm attempting to create is as follows:

```
DELIMITER // 

CREATE TRIGGER test 
    AFTER INSERT ON podcastranking
    FOR EACH ROW 

    BEGIN

        DECLARE temp_pod_id int; 
        DECLARE updated_rating int; 

        set temp_pod_id = SELECT podcast_id FROM inserted;
        set updated_rating = CALL get_podcast_rating_avg(temp_pod_id);

        UPDATE podcasts
            SET podcasts.ranking = updated_rating
            WHERE podcasts.id = temp_pod_id;

   END; //

DELIMITER ;
```

When I try to run this I receive the error message of:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT podcast_id FROM inserted;
        SET updated_rating = CALL get_podcast_' at line 10
```

Apologies if I'm making a mistake without knowing it, I'm fairly new to MySQL and hitting this is being a bit of a learning curve for me.

Thanks! :)

---

from P.Salmon's replies I've rewrote as

```
DELIMITER // 

    CREATE TRIGGER test 
        AFTER INSERT ON podcastranking
        FOR EACH ROW 

        BEGIN
            UPDATE podcasts
                SET podcasts.ranking = CALL get_podcast_rating_avg(SELECT podcast_id FROM new.values);
                WHERE podcasts.id = SELECT podcast_id FROM new.values ;
        END; //

DELIMITER ;
```

However I'm still getting an issue with it saying that my syntax is wrong.

Comment: You may be confusing functions and procedures, a function will return a scalar value. A procedure can return a scalar value but you haven't coded to capture a returned value and you cannot call a procedure in a set statement.

Comment: There is no inserted table in mysql - You can refer to NEW.values in the trigger (see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html) and If you are using a training guide which only refers to sql server you should throw it away.

Comment: @P.Salmon 

DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION calcPodAvg(pod_id int) RETURNS float(9,2)
BEGIN
  RETURN SELECT AVG(ranking)
     FROM podcastranking
        where podcast_id = temp_pod_id;
  
END$$
DELIMITER ;

So would something like this work instead of the sproc? Thanks for the replies :)